# Resize an element in function of the number of elements

Tags: html, css

I have four elements on a line. Every element has a width of 25%.

I want to remove one of the elements and change de width of the other elements to 33.333% automatically. And if I add the element again change de width to 25%.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code please?

Comment: Just use `display: flex;` on the container, and `flex: 1 0 0;` on the contents.